# How convert to array or json php soap __dorequest response?

Tags: php

this is _dorequest response. Response is xml string data.
I tried convert with simplexml_load_string() function and later return array but function result is empty.

`'<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Header/>
   <env:Body>
      <ns1:createNgiShipmentWithAddressResponse xmlns:ns1="http://yurticikargo.com.tr/NgiShipmentInterfaceServices" xmlns:ns2="http://yurticikargo.com.tr/NgiShipmentInterfaceServices" xmlns:ns3="http://yurticikargo.com.tr/WSExceptions/">
         <XShipmentDataResponse>
            <outFlag>0</outFlag>
            <projectId>18501</projectId>
            <specialFieldDataArray>
               <specialFieldName>53</specialFieldName>
               <specialFieldValue>SIP-1234885679</specialFieldValue>
            </specialFieldDataArray>
            <specialFieldDataArray>
               <specialFieldName>3</specialFieldName>
               <specialFieldValue>SIP-1234885679</specialFieldValue>
            </specialFieldDataArray>
         </XShipmentDataResponse>
      </ns1:createNgiShipmentWithAddressResponse>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>'`

Answer (score 0):

xml converted to array:

```
$xml = "$result"; //$result xml string
$xml_parser = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($xml_parser,$xml,$vals,$index);
xml_parser_free($xml_parser);
$sonuc = $vals[$index['NODENAME'][0]]["value"];
```